# Python, задача удалить каждый третий символ

Tags: python

Помогите решить задачу -  удалить каждый третий символ в строке.
Видел как решают через срезы, я пытаюсь решить через замену.
Код ниже:

```
s = input()
i = 0
while i != len(s):
    if i % 3 == 0:
        s = (s.replace(s[i], "$"))
        i += 1
    else:
        i += 1
print(s.replace('$', ''))
```

при вводе hello

оставляет eo

Работает в случае, если нет 2 подряд одинаковых символов. В противном случае - удаляет оба. Посоветуйте как это можно исправить?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Через замену не выйдет, потому что `replace` заменит в строке все такие символы, ему не важно, где этот символ находится, в той позиции, где вы его хотели заменить, или где-то ещё.

Поэтому вам нужно тем или иным способом считать позиции символов и убирать символы именно в нужных позициях, а не по значению самого символа. Позицию символа можно получать, например, с помощью `enumerate`:

```
s = 'hello1234567890'
print(''.join([x for i,x in enumerate(s) if i%3 != 2]))
# helo235689
```

Answer (score 1):

```
s = '1233435637839'
skip = 3
print(''.join([s[i:i + skip - 1] for i in range(0, len(s), skip)]))  # 123456789
```

Answer (score 1):

вот еще пара вариантов для разнообразия:

```
from re import sub

s='1234567890'
print(sub(r'(.{2})(.)',r'\1',s))

# 1245780
```

```
from itertools import compress, cycle

s='1234567890'
print(''.join(compress(s,cycle([1,1,0]))))

# 1245780
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, оставляйте чуть более развёрнутые ответы.
[Постарайтесь рассказать обо всех нюансах, которые могут возникнуть при решении проблемы по вашему сценарию.
Изложите свои предложения.
Возможен и краткий ответ, но чем подробнее и понятнее он будет изложен, тем лучше](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).
Дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit].

Comment: Прикольные варианты

Answer (score 0):

Через промежуточное преобразование в список и удаление элементов среза:

```
s = '123456789123456789'
s1 = list(s)
del s1[2::3]
print(''.join(s1))  # 124578124578
```

Comment: "Видел как решают через срезы, я пытаюсь решить через замену." )

Comment: Ну, не факт, что автор видел именно этот способ, может там через срезы строки решалось)